# Convert ObjectId to str in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, objectid

I am using MongoDB with Python and MongoEngine. I would like to convert all `_id` from `ObjectId` to `str` after each DB query. Is there any way to do this automatically or is there any function that recursively goes through object/array of objects and replaces all `ObjectId` with `str`? Now, I have to manually use `$toString`:

```
class User(Document):
    name = StringField()

users = User.objects.aggregate([
    {"$set": {"$toString": {"_id": "$_id"}}}
])
```

If I use `$lookup`, there will be nested `_id` in array, so I have to use even `$map`.

Comment: What is the reason to convert `ObjectId` into a string`? I cannot imagine any useful reason for it.

Comment: This is not posible, `_id` is immutable.

Comment: Try $convert...

Answer (score -1):

if `sampleDocument` is an object fetched from MongoDB the below snippet will give you string from `ObjectId`:

```
str(sampleDocument ._id)
```